# Clone git repository from one folder to another in Linux

Tags: git, file, git-clone

I uploaded a website to a shared server, and as I wanted to track changes I ran  `git init`on all the site files in the root folder of the shared server. This created a new subfolder `.git`.

I now want to create a copy of my site in a separate folder for developing and thought the easiest way would be to clone the existing repository to the new folder. My git repository exists at `/www/www/.git`. And I want to clone my repository to my development folder at `/www/test/`.

What command do I need to use to clone my git repository to the test folder?

I do not know the name of my git repository, it is just the master branch.

I have tried running:

```
git clone file://www/www/
```

And

```
git clone file://www/www/.git
```

As well as other combinations, but every time I get the same error message:

> fatal: '/www/www/.git' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I have checked the file permissions and there is read and write access to the git repository folder.

Can anyone tell me the correct command/method I should be using to clone my repository? One that will also make it easy for me to pull in any changes to the original repository.

Comment: Does that help git clone -l -s -n . ../copy? You can find it in the documentation.

Comment: I tried git clone file://www/www/.git -l -s -n, but that made no difference. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. But why do you use file://? Not just path/to/.git?

Comment: Ok, I tried git clone -l -s -n ../www and I still get an error: fatal: repository '.' does not exist

Comment: I thought I had to use file://. I tried it without (git clone ../www and it worked! Thank you! However it created a sub-folder 'www'. Is there a way I can clone it without creating the sub-folder?

Comment: Sorry, I worked it out: git clone -l -s -n ../www .
Thanks again for your help. If you want to give it as an answer I can confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `git clone -l -s -n ../www`. See [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> **-l/--l**: When the repository to clone from is on a local machine, this flag
>   bypasses the normal "Git aware" transport mechanism and clones the
>   repository by making a copy of HEAD and everything under objects and
>   refs directories. The files under .git/objects/ directory are
>   hardlinked to save space when possible.

and the (always?) hidden examples at the end of the page.

Comment: Many thanks. It also worked without the -l -s -n although seems like the -l would save space.